# Spaces in string vs. Escape sequences

Tags: ruby, string

In Ruby (testing in the Interactive Ruby Shell), you can either use spaces in strings or use escape sequences. Is there a best practice in determining which to use, or does it never matter?

For example:

```
"Hello World"

--> "Hello World"

vs.

"Hello\sWorld"

--> "Hello World"
```

Comment: using space is a lot easier.

Comment: It makes a difference for single quoted strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spaces. Makes it much more easier to read

If you cant, then use the escape sequences.

Also note that escape only works in double quotes

```
   'Hello\sWolrd'
    --> 'Hello\\sWorld'
```